# RAD Editor Telerik control image Manager, and asp.net button issues (Not working together)

Tags: asp.net, image, button, controls

In writing and in telling its strange thing is happening with me. Let me tel you scene from first, i am using RAD editor with following code

```
<telerik:radeditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" Width="550px" ToolsFile="Tool.xml" skin="WebBlue" height="400" BackColor="LightGray" tabindex="6">
<ImageManager ViewPaths="~/Images/" UploadPaths="~/Images/" DeletePaths="~/Images/" />
<MediaManager ViewPaths="~/Images/" UploadPaths="~/Images/" DeletePaths="~/Images/" />
<FlashManager ViewPaths="~/Images/" UploadPaths="~/Images/" DeletePaths="~/Images/" />
<DocumentManager ViewPaths="~/Images/" UploadPaths="~/Images/" DeletePaths="~/Images/" />
</telerik:radeditor>
```

now with this i am not able to upload image with this image manager, so i got solutions from stackoverflow to add some script in web.confing as it is bellow, i got solution to upload image with image manager. but some how my buttons of site stops to work.

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules>
<add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
<add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler"/> 
</modules>
<handlers>
<add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
<add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode"/>         <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx_*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI"preCondition="integratedMode"/>
<add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/></handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

so please get me idea how this can be happen and what i have to do for this or any alternative solution to get work Image Manager (FYI: with above code i am able to upload image but asp.net button controls stop working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your handlers look a bit off to me.  Here are the handlers I have in my web.config for some Telerik controls (I don't use their files managers, I programmed my own for custom functionality).

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<handlers>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" />
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
</handlers>
```

The fact that some of yours are ending with _* doesn't look right.

Comment: yes it works thanks thanks thanks you i had lost my day and you did it in just a fraction of time thanks alot